# Create a SparseVector from the elements of RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, scala-collections

Using Spark, I have a data structure of type `val rdd = RDD[(x: Int, y:Int), cov:Double]` in Scala, where each element of the RDD represents an element of a matrix with `x` representing the row, `y` representing the column and `cov` representing the value of the element:

I need to create SparseVectors from rows of this matrix. So I decided to first convert the rdd to `RDD[x: Int, (y:Int, cov:Double)]` and then use groupByKey to  put all elements of a specific row together like this:

`val rdd2 = rdd.map{case ((x,y),cov) => (x, (y, cov))}.groupByKey()`

Now I need to create the SparseVectors:

```
val N = 7     //Vector Size
val spvec = {(x: Int,y: Iterable[(Int, Double)]) => new SparseVector(N.toLong, Array(y.map(el => el._1.toInt)), Array(y.map(el => el._2.toDouble)))}
val vecs = rdd2.map(spvec)
```

However, this is the error that pops up.

```
type mismatch; found :Iterable[Int] required:Int
type mismatch; found :Iterable[Double] required:Double
```

I am guessing that `y.map(el => el._1.toInt)` is returning an iterable which Array cannot be applied on. I would appreciate if someone could help with how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to convert to `RowMatrix`:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.{CoordinateMatrix, MatrixEntry}

val rdd: RDD[((Int, Int), Double)] = ???

val vs: RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector]= new CoordinateMatrix(
  rdd.map{
    case ((x, y), cov) => MatrixEntry(x, y, cov)
  }
).toRowMatrix.rows.map(_.toSparse)
```

If you want to preserve row indices you can use `toIndexedRowMatrix` instead:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.IndexedRow

new CoordinateMatrix(
  rdd.map{
    case ((x, y), cov) => MatrixEntry(x, y, cov)
  }
).toIndexedRowMatrix.rows.map { case IndexedRow(i, vs) => (i, vs.toSparse) }
```

Comment: Thank you. It works for `toRowMatrix` but not for `toIndexedRowMatrix` saying `value toSparse is not a member of org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.IndexedRow`. I do want to preserve the row indices.

Comment: Because it contains `IndexedRows`  not `Vectors`.